# Laravel backpack 4.1 Add anchor tag to table

Tags: laravel-backpack

How to make a link from a database field and display it inside the table?
[image]

Inside the `protected function setupListOperation()` the code for the link looks like this:

```
 CRUD::column('link')->type('link');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the wrapper attributes to turn that into an anchor. See the docs here - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-columns#wrap-column-text-in-an-html-element